# jQuery mouseenter mouseleave hover bug

Tags: jquery, mouseover, jquery-hover, mouseenter

I'm attempting to apply an opacity change on my LI elements by toggling the 'active' class, but neither mouse events or hover are working.  Looks like a simple fix but i can't figure out why.

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('nav.li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $('nav.li').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

  $("nav.li").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

css

```
nav.li.active {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="about_link">...</li>
    <li class="contact_link">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your don't need the `.` here between `nav` and `li`, so you can change:

```
$('nav.li')
```

to:

```
$('nav li')
```

Final code look like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("nav li").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Your current selector `$('nav.li')` is matching the `<nav>` element with class `li`. You also need to change your css to:

```
nav li.active {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTvC5/)**

Comment: Okay so i'm just using the hover method now, but why is my class not toggling off upon leaving the hover?  Right now it is only toggling on when i hover, and off when i leave and re-hover.

Comment: Did you check my demo? The class `active` is toggle on and off when you mouse over and leave the `li` element

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript:**

Change your selector from:

```
$('nav.li')
```

to:

```
$('nav li')
```

Currently, your selector is targeting a `<nav>` element with a class of *li*. I think you want to target the `<li>` elements inside the `<nav>` element.

You can optimize your jQuery by chaining the calls together as well:

```
// Shorthand document ready...
$(function () {
    $('nav li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

You'll need to modify your CSS accordingly too:

```
nav li.active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

You may want to consider expanding this to include vendor prefixes as well for maximum compatibility:

```
nav li.active {
    /* IE 8 - 9 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";

    /* IE 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:0.7;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;

    /* Modern!
     * Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any, Opera 9+, IE 9+ 
     */
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

[Opacity Reference Guide](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)